# How to connect scheduler and workers in airflow?

Tags: azure, airflow

We have configured a webserver a scheduler and a VMSS for workers in airflow. Have created the postgre for Metadata information for all Airflow related activities like tasks, connections , redis for For orchestrating the workers and azure blob storage for logging . Have created a sample dag and when triggered the dag keeps on running and is not executed.I find my scheduler workers and webserver up and working fine am not sure why my jobs are not picked by the scheduler. Is there any connection that I could have missed ? Kindly let me know on the same.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have set a FERNET_KEY and its the same across Webserver, Scheduler and Workers. 
To generate FERNET_KEY
https://bcb.github.io/airflow/fernet-key